# Sort an ArrayList of Points in page line order

Tags: java, sorting, points

I need to order an ArrayList of Points in the page line order. Assume these points as minX and minY of Rectangle of text.

Say like I have points like below

Point(100,10), Point(110, 20), Point(125, 5), Point(130, 10)

The Sorted order should be aligned as page line items

i.e Point(125, 5), Point(100,10), Point(130, 10), Point(110, 20)

I was trying to sort the Points by Y coordinate first and then by X coordinate

```
public int compare(final Point a, final Point b) {
    if (a.y() < b.y()) {
        return -1;
    }else if (a.y() > b.y()) {
        return 1;
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public int compare(final Point a, final Point b) {
    if (a.x() < b.x()) {
        return -1;
    }else if (a.x() > b.x()) {
        return 1;
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

[image]

Below is the order I am getting now

Line = 0.00 2450 00 SewiceTax @14 on are, Sub Total   Two Thousand Four Hundred Fifty Only INR

Line = Swachh Bharat Cass @ O 50 42':

Line = Knshu Kaiyan Cass @ 0‘50 “5

Line = Less Advance Paid

Line = 2450 GD Balance Payable

Expected was

**Line =   Sub Total  Two Thousand Four Hundred Fifty Only 0.00 2450 00INR SewiceTax @14 on are,**

Comment: Your attempt? Show the code you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  I'm sure there is a SO question which already covers how to create a customer comparator for a point class, to be used when sorting a list of points.

Comment: Would be nice to see what you already tried, we are not here to programm you an algorithm^^

Comment: Use comparator in Point class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort by multiple columns, Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204594/sort-by-multiple-columns-java-8)

Comment: Have updated the question with the code and the actual and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. Sort the Points by Y coordinate first and then by X coordinate.

```
Point p1 = new Point(12,  15);
Point p2 = new Point(13,  12);
Point p3 = new Point(14,  15);

List<Point> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(p1);
list.add(p2);
list.add(p3);

Comparator<Point> comp = new Comparator<Point>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return p2.y  == p1.y ? p2.x -p1.x : p2.y-p1.y;
    }
};
list.sort(comp);
```

Comment: looks promising.. I'll check and let you know. may be the order I have to change.. np man I'll up vote.  there are some people just for this...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), and override compare() according to your usecase.
These links will help you

[How to sort ArrayList using Comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314009/how-to-sort-arraylist-using-comparator)

[How to use Comparator in Java to sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort)